# How to send appointment with Azure service

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there any service on Azure, which can be used to send meeting invite using C# code.  Currently, I am sending SendGrid to send email. But I also need to send appointments (meeting invite).

Comment: S.O. != Google Search

Comment: Well a meeting invite arrives as an email...just in a specific format.

Comment: does SendGrid support it?

Answer (score 0):

Sendgrid supports email attachment, you can use this [`snippet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45076896/send-email-as-calendar-invite-appointment-in-sendgrid-c-sharp) in order to send an email.

Also with Azure Logic App [`O365 connector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/), you can send a calendar invitation.

Comment: Above snippet work and send file as ics file.  But doesn't add it to calendar after opening it.